# Cordova Windows 10 - Exception calling native with command - notification

Tags: javascript, windows, cordova, win-universal-app

I am having trouble with my Windows 10 cordova application.

I am trying to use the navigator.notification.confirm but it keeps throwing me this error

> Exception calling native with command :: Notification :: confirm
>   ::exception=WinRTError: The parameter is incorrect

I am running this command on another page and it is running fine. I don't know why it is working on one page and not another.

This is the code for my index page - **WORKS FINE**

```
navigator.notification.confirm(
    'This will download new data, do you want to confirm?',
    'callback',
    'Are you sure?',
    ['Refresh', 'Cancel']
)
```

However, the code below doesn't work at all and I don't know why at all

```
navigator.notification.confirm(
    'Please select an option',
    ImageCaptureInput.currentInstance.onConfirm2,
    'Photo / video',
    ['Photo','Cancel','Video']     
);
```

I have this working on WP8, Android and iOS and it works fine. Windows 10 throws this unknown error. Having a Google around and a quick look on here didn't help at all.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I get these errors in the debug console in Visual Studio. It seems the error is only with the confirm function of the navigator.notification plugin.

```
0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: InvalidAccessError
Exception was thrown at line 221, column 13 in ms-appx-web://cordova.platform.windowsUWP/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-dialogs/src/windows/NotificationProxy.js
0x80070057 - JavaScript runtime error: The parameter is incorrect.
Exception was thrown at line 240, column 13 in ms-appx-web://cordova.platform.windowsUWP/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-dialogs/src/windows/NotificationProxy.js
```

2ND EDIT

The error seems to be occurring when it gets to the showAsync() part of the function, shown below

```
confirm:function(win, loseX, args) {

    if (isAlertShowing) {
        var later = function () {
            module.exports.confirm(win, loseX, args);
        };
        alertStack.push(later);
        return;
    }

    isAlertShowing = true;

    try {
        var message = args[0];
        var _title = args[1];
        var buttons = args[2];

        var md = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(message, _title);

        buttons.forEach(function(buttonLabel) {
            md.commands.append(new Windows.UI.Popups.UICommand(buttonLabel));
        });

        md.showAsync().then(function(res) {
            isAlertShowing = false;
            var result = res ? buttons.indexOf(res.label) + 1 : 0;
            if (win) {
                win(result);
            }
            if (alertStack.length) {
                setTimeout(alertStack.shift(), 0);
            }

        });
    } catch (e) {
        // set isAlertShowing flag back to false in case of exception
        isAlertShowing = false;
        if (alertStack.length) {
            setTimeout(alertStack.shift(), 0);
        }
        // rethrow exception
        throw e;
    }
},
```

Comment: I tried it in a blank empty project, there is no problem for that. Could you please share a basic demo that can reproduce the problem?

Comment: I have even just made the page blank and used one button to call this and it still produces the same error. I used jsconsole.com to log any errors, and the only one that is showing is the one above. Also, the proxy's have been added for every plugin, just like the index.html page, but still no avail

Comment: What exactly is `ImageCaptureInput.currentInstance.onConfirm2`? Is this a string, or maybe a function? Also, your first (working) code sample has broken syntax; `'`s are not balanced.

Comment: It's a function. Sorry that was my bad, it fine in my code i just accidentally deleted one ' when I copied it into here